# Why does IEnumerable<char> ToString() work in xamarin android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

<s>In C# you cannot override the `ToString()` method of an `IEnumerable`.</s>
**It's polymorphism what I missed**.

Therefore this

```
IEnumerable<char> chars = new List<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
chars.ToString();
```

doesn't give me "abc".

Looking into some Xamarin.Android I wonder how the following converts into the correct string:

```
//In OnCreate
FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.txt_username).TextChanged += GenerateNewPassword;


//my method
private void GenerateNewPassword(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    passwordView.Text = e.Text.ToString();
}
```

What am I missing, why does this work?

Comment: But what actual type is it? What is the true type inside the `IEnumerable<char>` returned from `.Text`? (I don't have anything Xamarin installed that I can use to check).. A string can be treated as an `IEnumerable<char>`: `IEnumerable<char> x = "hello"`  and you can call ToString() on it, which, because it's a `string`, will just return the string..

Comment: *you cannot override the ToString() method of an IEnumerable* - the IEnumerable interface imposes a restriction on the overridability of ToString? Really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ToString` override is coming from the underlying type, not the `IEnumerable<T>`. I'm not sure how Xamarin is providing that exactly, but I presume it is a custom type that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. For example, we can do this:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Join("", this);
    }
}
```

And now we can do this:

```
IEnumerable<char> chars = new MyList<char> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
Console.WriteLine(chars.ToString());
```

Which will output:

> abc

Comment: Well I forgot about polymorphism. Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that Xamarin is using `Java.Lang.ICharSequence` under the hood.